# White hat security community

Tags: security, community

A while ago I remember there existed a community of savvy people who would probe a server for common vulnerabilities, this was a voluntary project but not even google can help me find it, I was hoping that if anyone knows of such a community they could point me to it.

Thanks

Comment: This would go better on http://security.stackexchange.com